How to troubleshoot an (HFS+) external drive no longer being detected by macOS Catalina
I have an external USB drive that uses HFS+ and it worked fine for more than a year until a few days ago. Last week, I got the error Drive was not ejected properly ... 2 times. It however worked fine when it was removed and re-plugged to the USB port. I didn't do a filesystem check / repair through Disk Utility as it continued to work fine. Now, macOS Catalina just refuses to detect the drive at all.
The troubleshooting I've done so far:

Check in Disk Utility - the drive is not shown.
Check with diskutil list command in Terminal - the drive doesn't appear in the list.
Check in System Information > USB section - the drive isn't shown connected.
Use a different USB cable with the disk drive - no change; drive is still not detected.
Check if all the USB ports work with another pen drive - all work fine.
Repeat step 1 to 3 in Safe Mode - the drive is not detected in Safe Mode too.
Go to Recovery Mode and check with diskutil list command - the drive isn't listed.
Remove all USB devices except keyboard, mouse and the drive - disk still not detected.
Reset PRAM - still no drive detected.
Reset SMC - still no drive detected.
Run sudo diskutil activity - no messages generated when drive is plugged and unplugged.
Check in Console. Log when drive is plugged to USB port:


default   21:31:08.504203+0530    icdd                   Added | [USB][          Game Drive ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x14500000 |
default   21:31:11.798926+0530    kernel  Notice - new kext com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPlatformProperties, v1.2 matches prelinked kext but can't determine if executables are the same (no UUIDs).
default   21:31:11.848612+0530    icdd                Inferior | [USB][          Game Drive ] ( 8, 6,50) @ 0x14500000 |
default   21:31:11.845199+0530    kernel  USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 57583832453130394E32544B 0x1058 0x262f 0x5002, 3
default   21:31:53.212439+0530    kernel  USB device 1058262F14500000 - BOT reset completed with kIOReturnTimeout.
default   21:31:53.513587+0530    kernel  USB device 1058262F14500000 - will be reset!
default   21:31:54.881092+0530    kernel  USB device 1058262F14500000 - fConsecutiveResetCount = 1.
default   21:31:54.883295+0530    icdd               [Removed] | [USB][          Game Drive ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x14500000 |
default   21:31:54.883424+0530    icdd               [Removed] | [USB][          Game Drive ] ( 8, 6,50) @ 0x14500000 |
default   21:31:54.882997+0530    kernel  IOUSBMassStorageResource: bad busy count (0,-1)
Backtrace 0xffffff80009fe8a6 0xffffff7f81a03436 0xffffff8000a2a5de 0xffffff8000a01894 0xffffff8000a0bd87 0xffffff80002c113e 0x0
default   21:31:54.883028+0530    kernel           com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver(157.140.1)[61A8ACED-1488-36C8-9B78-47B81C0653D4]@0xffffff7f81a01000->0xffffff7f81a34fff
default   21:31:54.883050+0530    kernel              dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[132A3039-5B42-38C4-A6DB-F450EAE64E0C]@0xffffff7f80f7c000

I also noticed that during the period when the process icdd says "Added" and then "Removed" (after a few minutes), VMWare shows the USB disk drive briefly in its USB list (even when macOS shows no traces of it).
What should I do next? I don't have access to another system right now but I can probably create a USB Linux live disk and boot into it to check the drive (but then, I will also have to contemplate what's the point of using macOS at all if I need to turn to another OS ...? :).

This sounds like a cable/connector problem (bad contact, broken wire, something like that). Do you have another USB cable to try? Also, try wiggling things while watching the Console log, and see if you get connects/disconnects.

@GordonDavisson Note step 4 - I have already tried using a different, working USB cable from another drive. It didn't help.
